# Image disappear on UIImage

Tags: iphone

What I had done is:

I have one IBOutlet for UIImageVIew and

```
[self.imgPView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
```

and on somewhere,
I had show AlertView

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Problem is already submitted, Do you want to submit again?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
    alert.tag = kProblemSubmitAlert;
    [alert show];
```

while UIAlertView displays, Image on ImageView disappers,
Any Idea?

Comment: Can you also include your UIAlertViewDelegate methods?  Does the image disappear before the UIAlertView appears, or after you have tapped one of the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it’s a caching issue, you may have success through initialize your `UIImage` using `+imageNamed:` instead of `+imageWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: I don't know it is cache issue or not. But image is not disappearing if I put image on interface builder.